# Integral of a fraction of series

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, fourier-series

I'm interested in evaluating the following integral

$$\mathcal{J} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\sin(kx)\,e^{-tk^2}}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos(kx)\,e^{-tk^2}} \, \mathrm{d}t$$

I think I've seen this before somewhere. Inverse Fourier? However, I do not remember where I've seen it and I do not have any starting point to begin cracking it.

The answer is supposed to be $\displaystyle \frac{\pi^2 ( \pi - x )}{8}$ for $0<x<2\pi$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How did you prove this integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337593/how-did-you-prove-this-integral). It seems that the result doesn't hold actually. Btw, you also asked it before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2306105/515527).

Comment: It does. I totally forgot about it! Thanks!! :)